# Extracting Metadata with Tika as RDF

Tags: java, metadata, apache-tika, xmp

I'm using Tika to extract Metadata from many types (images, video, etc...) using the AutoDetectParser. It works quiet well and returns some metadata in a full qualified naming style "tiff:XResolution" (xmp).

But if I compare a Metadata extraction from Tika and a rdf extraction from exiftool for instance, I can see that Tika don't returns as many metadata.

Is there a programmatic way to retrieve every XMP metadata with Tika, as exiftool does ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a a programmatic way to retrieve XMP metadata with Tika.

Look at this: [org.apache.tika.xmp.XMPMetadata](https://tika.apache.org/1.14/api/org/apache/tika/xmp/XMPMetadata.html)

If you have a maven project, you need to insert this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-xmp</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

in your pom.xml (of course, you need other tika dependencies such as tika-core and tika-parsers)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll look at this